# Hashlib returning duplicate hash when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, hashlib

I'm using hashlib to create a sha256 hash of a file, which is then compared against the previous hash of the file which is stored in a database.

```
def create_hash(file, id, hex=True, hash_type=hashlib.sha256):
    con = db.connect(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_db)
    cur = con.cursor()
    hashinst = hash_type()
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(hashinst.block_size * 128), b''):
                hashinst.update(chunk)
            hash = hashinst.hexdigest() if hex else hashinst.digest()
    print hash
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Previews WHERE S_Id=%s", (id))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    count = row[2] + 1
    cur_hash = row[1]
    if hash == cur_hash:
        count = row[2] + 1
        cur.execute("UPDATE Previews SET Count = %s WHERE S_Id = %s", (count, id))
        con.commit()
    elif hash != cur_hash:
        cur.execute("UPDATE Previews SET Count = 0 WHERE S_Id = %s", (id))
        con.commit()
        cur.execute("UPDATE Previews SET Hash = %s WHERE S_Id = %s", (hash, id))    
        con.commit()
```

Speed is a must for this so I am also using the multiprocessing module.

```
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes= pCount)
    pool.map(create_preview, rows)
```

This calls a function `create_preview` which creates the images and calls the function above. The issue is that all the hashes are the same. If I do this within a for loop instead of using the multiprocessing pool i have no issues and all the hashes are different.

Does anyone know of any issues these may be with using the hashlib module and multiprocessing or an alternate method which I could use to compare the files?

Comment: Are you sure that problem in `hashlib`? I'm thinking that you are parsing same file several times.

Comment: The function the pool calls creates the file, which then uses the file path of what its just created the call the other function to create the hash. As I said in my post i had no issues when i eliminated the multiprocessing pool for a for loop.

Comment: What's going on when you change 'pool.map' on just a 'map'. Is it same result or not?

Comment: It runs in one process and I get exactly the same outcome, duplicate hashes.

Comment: Can you show code of correct 'for' loop?

Comment: for row in rows:
 create_preview(row[0])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you should use `map(lambda row: create_preview(row[0]), rows)` instead of `map(create_preview, rows)`.

Comment: still the same outcome.

Comment: still the same for simple `map`? Because it's absolute analogue of your `for loop`.

Comment: Sorry, yes i incorrectly put in your command as i had to tweak it a little to get it work as row is an int so I could not index it.Thanks for your help!